# Rock, Scissors, Paper

Tags: java, jpanel

I just made a Rock, Scissors, paper game and have come a bit far until now. I don't really know anymore (Been trying a while) to make the game stop when user or computer hits 3 points first.

I have some thoughts to make a if statement == 3 = wins. But if I do that, then the button should be disabled too.. I was thinking something like that but I cant just get it anymore! So ideas would be great!

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int Choice= 0;

        if(e.getSource() == exit) {
            this.dispose();
            System.exit(0); 
        }
        else if(e.getSource() == newgame) {
            this.dispose();
            new RockScissorsPaper();
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == Rock) {
            Choice= Rock;       
        }
        else if (e.getSource() == Scissors) {
            Choice= Scissors;
        }
        else {
            Choice= Paper; 
        }
        calculate(Choice);

    }//actionPerformed


     / ** 
     * Computer game selection is randomized and compared with the user 
     * Choice (method arguments). The game result is stored and displayed 
     * UI. 
     * / 
    public void calculate(int val){

        //Get user choise
        UserChoose= val;     

        // randomise the computer's choice and typing on the integer
        ComputerChoose = (int)(Math.random() * 3);

        //show result

        resultatLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0); 
        infoLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(0);    
        infoLabel.setText("Result round " + ++round +":");  

        if (UserChoose == ComputerChoose)
            resultatLabel.setText("Tie!");   

        else if (UserChoose == Rock &&  ComputerChoose == Scissors || 
                UserChoose == Scissors &&  ComputerChoose == Paper||
                UserChoose == Paper &&  ComputerChoose == Rock) {
            resultatLabel.setText("You win! One more game?");
            användarResultat.setText(" Your wins: " + ++UserWins+ "st");
        }
        else {
            resultatLabel.setText(" You Lose! Try again!");
            datorResultat.setText(" Computer wins: " + ++computerWins + "st");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RockScissorsPaper();
    }


}
```

Comment: Please translate this code to English and paste only the necessary code, not the whole program.

Comment: Ok will do it! hold on.

Answer (score 0):

Just add attributes to your `Stensaxpase`class, something like

```
private int numberOfWinsUser;
private int numberOfWinsComputer;
```

And each time someone wins (in `berakna`) you update them and check if someone has reached 3 wins. Since this event driven, there is no need to use a loop.

Comment: Hmmm. Im kinda off my mind. I do undestand what you mean but im still kinda lost how I should do it. Whats on my mind is that. 

If numberOfWinsUser == 3 {
 "You win"
 else (numberOfWinsComputer == 3 {
" You lose "

Comment: @Barry Standard structure is `while (!endOfTheGame){ play the game }  handle end of the game`

Comment: I was more thinking. If I do now a If statement by using "First who reached 3 wins, wins the game" but the problem is then, how do I disable the buttons so they wont work?

Comment: Is there anyone that can help me out?